Upgrading from 1.17.4 to 1.19.0 directly?
We have a handful of SPFx webparts in version 1.17.4. We want to upgrade to a higher version, most likely 1.19.0. So my simple plan is to upgrade to 1.18.0, change Node version to 18, and then upgrade directly to 1.19.0.
It would also be "nice" to change to TypeScript version 4.7, just to keep up with the progress.
Should we upgrade semi-directly as planned, or rather go through all the versions step by step?

Check these and let me know if it helps/works to upgrade: 1. How it works: spfx project upgrade and 2. spfx project upgrade

cool thanks, I'm using the CLI now, will report back after I work my way through the runtime error messages

Sure, let me know how it goes.
